# lubuntu extra apps website's methods not working!

Tags: lubuntu, ubuntu-tweak, compton, menulibre

https://lubuntu.me/get-extra-apps-for-lubuntu/ when I tried these steps it just resulted :

```
Unable to locate package lubuntu-tweaks
Unable to locate package xombrero
```

Comment: Please also include the output of `apt policy lubuntu-tweaks` when you make the requested edit.

Comment: That's an *ancient* thread that has since been yanked by the Lubuntu Team because it's infinitely old.  The PPA is dead.  LXDE is dead.  The PPA has been dead for years.

Answer (score 3):

The only apps in the PPA you mention are no longer relevant to anything Lubuntu supports.

The team that provides support are [https://launchpad.net/~lubuntu-dev](https://launchpad.net/%7Elubuntu-dev)

Those *apps* were for very old releases of Lubuntu/LXDE which are [no longer supported](https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/), as such the PPA was disabled and packages removed as they'll just create problems for Lubuntu users who will now be using the *modern* LXQt desktop.

This was done some time ago, and the packages were all *xenial* (16.04) and older *if I remember correctly* (eg. the link you used was from six years ago!). We had no packages in the PPA for *bionic* or anything more modern, though *bionic* packages would have been removed as well as we no longer support Lubuntu 18.04 LTS.